# Losing view model context in a knockout.js component loaded by requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I have a strange problem with knockout js component loaded by require js.
The component is very simple.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'knockout'
], function ($, ko) {


    function ViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;
        this.test = 'test';
    }

    ViewModel.prototype.fetchData = function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.test);
    };

    ViewModel.prototype.init = function() {
        console.log(this.test);
        this.fetchData();
    };

    ko.components.register('my-component', {
        viewModel: ViewModel,
        template: '<span data-bind="template: { afterRender: init }"></span>'
    });

});
```

Now, the **template** binding is able to call the view models **init** method, but this method itself can not access the **fetchData** method, because inside the method **this** is bound to the Window object instead of the view model.

I prepared a fiddle to show the error case: http://jsfiddle.net/ask4artur/3f6jsa4m/47/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* knockout does not call the `afterRender` method in the this-context of `$data` automatically. You can set `$data` as `this` by using `bind` like so:

```
data-bind="template: { afterRender: init.bind($data) }
```

```js
var i = 0;

var ViewModel = function() {
   this.nr = "Instance " + i++; 
}

ViewModel.prototype.logNr = function() {
    console.log(this.nr);
};

ko.components.register('test', {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<div data-bind="template: { name: \'testTemplate\', afterRender: logNr.bind($data) }"></div>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="component: {name: 'test'}"></div>
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'test'}"></div>
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'test'}"></div>
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'test'}"></div>
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'test'}"></div>


<script type="text/html" id="testTemplate">
  <div data-bind="text: nr, click: logNr"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Bingo!. That's it!. Thank You!